# Free Delivery Code Applying to Products Not deilvery

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon-codes, free-shipping

When setting up our free delivery code within Shopping cart price rules (see settings laid out) I notice that the discount value is being removed from the product lines and not from the shipping value. Do we have our settings for this coupon incorrect and if not what is the best way to apply this type of rule properly?

Thanks

Settings: 
Conditions>
Shipping country is UK
Actions>
Apply fixed discount to whole cart, value £5.95.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have it currently set, it is trying to apply a single discount to the whole basket, which it appears to be doing by deducting smaller amounts from each product.

However, since you are only looking to remove the shipping charge (as I understand from above) then it would be better to change the action as follows:

Apply: Fixed amount discount
Discount amount: 0
Apply to Shipping Amount: No
Free Shipping: For shipment with matching items

This would then apply free shipping for any order containing items matched by your conditions. The other option on Free Shipping would grant free shipping only on items in the basket that qualified, potentially leaving a charge on some items.

[image: Price rule actions]